# How to send AE A7 04 00 05 09 BC B7 command to BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-ble

I need to send AE A7 04 00 05 09 BC B7 command to BLE device. Can You help me to manage it ? I mean what and how have I to do after connection to device ?

```
public void WriteValue(String strValue)
    {
            mNotifyCharacteristic.setValue("AE A7 04 00 05 09 BC B7".getBytes());
            mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mNotifyCharacteristic);
            boolean sendStatus = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mNotifyCharacteristic);"+mNotifyCharacteristic.getProperties());
    }

@Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                        int status)
        {
            Log.d("TESTING","status !!!= "+status);
        }
```

Comment: It is unclear to me what you have to send. Is that a string?

Comment: How I understand I can send only byte array so in the end I am doing this convertation:
mNotifyCharacteristic.setValue("AE A7 04 00 05 09 BC B7".getBytes());
mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mNotifyCharacteristic);

But I am not sure that I get the sending process right...

Comment: It is easy to try some writes. Isnt there a write(bytes) ?

Comment: Yes there are, but I am getting status=0, so someting is wrong

Comment: Ask them how many bytes you had to send for the 'string' you mentioned. In the way you do it now you would send 23 bytes. But it could be that the receiver only expects 8 bytes. Quite possible.

Comment: About which status are you talking? You should show us relevant code. In your post. Not in comments of course.

Comment: Just updated the code.

The reciver wait exactly for AE A7 04 00 05 09 BC B7.

Comment: That is not expressed exact. How many bytes would that be? Does the receiver expect spaces?

Comment: `"+mNotifyCharacteristic.getProperties());` ????

Comment: `WriteValue(String strValue)`. You are not writing that string value.

Comment: I think this line writes: mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mNotifyCharacteristic);

Comment: just forgot to delete it mNotifyCharacteristic.getProperties()

Comment: How many bytes would that be --- as the command is, about spaces: I do not know, there is nothing about it in doc

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your string properly to a byte array using a hex to byte array conversion rather than just taking the ascii value of each character.

Comment: Can You give an example, please ? Currently I am doing in this way:
    public void WriteValue(String strValue)
    {
        mNotifyCharacteristic.setValue(strValue.getBytes());
        mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mNotifyCharacteristic);
    }

Comment: You have the answer here https://www.google.se/search?q=java+hex+to+byte+array. But make sure to remove the spaces in your string first.

Comment: I have changed the code to this one, but the result is the same:
String s="AEA704000509BCB7";
        byte[] b = new BigInteger(s,16).toByteArray();

        mNotifyCharacteristic.setValue(b);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mNotifyCharacteristic);